# Override container.html.twig template for a specific context

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to override the container.html.twig template but the twig debugging tool doesn't give any suggestion.

I tried to add suggestion following https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249565/85029 answer but I end up with the suggestion being container----.html.twig.

The context is a display field with an embed view in a node.

I guess, the solution might be pretty close from what I have now (using the suggestion hook) but I'm not able to have some satisfying suggestion.

My current hook is

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_container_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  if (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] == 'view') {
    $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $element['#name'];
    $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $element['#name'] . '__' . $element['#display_id'];
  }

  if (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] == 'container' && isset($element['children']['#type'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $element['children']['#type'];
  }
}
```

Edit :

Ended up with something corresponding to my expectations by adding

```
if (isset($element[0]) && $element[0]["#theme"]) {
    foreach ($element[0]["#theme"] as $themElem) {
        $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $themElem;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I just did this a month ago for the same reason:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_container_alter().
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_container_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  if (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] == 'view') {
    $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $element['#name'];
    $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $element['#name'] . '__' . $element['#display_id'];
  }

  if (isset($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] == 'container' && isset($element['children']['#type'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $element['children']['#type'];
  }
}
```

This will work for Views and general types. It is coming up blank because you need to handle it a little differently depending on whats being rendered.

Then in my twig file I am just doing:

`{{ children }}`

because I didn't want wrapping divs.

Comment: It seems none of the two conditions are filled in my case since I don't have any suggestion with that code :s
Might it be because I used an infinite scroll view for my view ?

Comment: It shouldn’t matter, it’s still a View. Did you clear the cache? Are you sure the code is being hit?

Comment: I've cleared the cache and the code is being hit since removing a condition give me a suggestion of container----

Comment: Did you debug it? Whats in `$suggestions`? Whats in `$variables`?

Comment: Is `$suggestions` defined correctly as being modifiable? You should post the code you have.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and suggestions is modifiable, I can add suggestions as container--1234

Comment: $variable contains #theme-wrappers #attributes #printed #cache #attached #children #render-children

Comment: Please update the original question with your code.

Comment: Good answer. I added "view" to the suggestion name so it's clear in my templates that it's a view container. ```$suggestions[] = 'container__view__' . $element['#name'];```

Answer (score 2):

Initially based on Kevin's code, the [Template Suggest](https://www.drupal.org/project/twigsuggest) module now includes container template suggestions.  An example of what it will provide for a view:

```
 FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * container--view--case-study--page-listing.html.twig
   * container--view--case-study.html.twig
   x container--view.html.twig
   * container--no-parent.html.twig
   * container.html.twig
```

Comment: How do you get Template Suggest to produce output???
Typical Drupal Contrib fashion- not a shred of documentation :(

Comment: @sea26.2 Enable the module and it provides template suggestions for the scenarios [documented on its project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/twigsuggest).  You can see the suggestions it (and anything else) provides by [enabling twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates).

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_container_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_container_alter(array &$suggestions, array $element)
{
    if (isset($element['element'][0]) && $element['element'][0]["#theme"]) {
        foreach ($element['element'][0]["#theme"] as $them_item) {
            $suggestions[] = 'container__' . $them_item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :)! Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately you posted a code-only answer. Maybe you can add some explanation why you think your snippet should work for OP.